How to find files from drive C: in the Recycle bin on Windows 10?
To get more free space on C: [SSD], I moved files of an installed application [6,7 GB] from C:\directory to D:\directory and created a corresponding softlink, but free space on C: is as small as before:

I expected deleting the files from C:\directory only transfers them into the Recycle Bin on C:, so I now would have to delete them from the Recycle Bin to reduce the used space, but the Recycle Bin only shows deleted files from D: and E:. I also don´t find any settings in the Recycle Bin where I unintentionally could have advised the Recycle Bin to show only files from D: and E: (even opening the Recycle Bin via PowerShell does not help to see these files)

How can I get these files selectable in the Recycle Bin so I delete them?

If you moved files from one location to another then those files are absolutely not located in the recycle bin. What’s the correlation to dragging and dropping files to a new location and the recycle bin?

What utility or method are you using to check the free space available on the disk? Please note that your question currently does not make sense. It seems you're making some assumptions regarding moving files and their being deleted, which is incorrect, and basing some further questions on that incorrect assumption. Please be more precise in your problem description, clearly state the problem, what you've done leading up to the problem, how you collected data and information.

Yes, Disk Cleanup did the job; now I have again 7 GB free. Thanks, John!

My (deleted) comments turned into a potential answer. Explorer may still be counting the symlink/junction for file size on the C drive. While it might depend on the manner the symlink was created, this is known behavior for windows explorer; dir; and powershell (among others).
If this is the case, then the space is free on disk, but the 6.7gb is still summed up in the total in-use number presented. Related discussion: stackoverflow.com/questions/54215968
I am unsure, but I think that this will still confuse windows and throw up out-of-space errors potentially in certain contexts. You can test this theory by unlinking and checking the free space reported.
